# MysoL for Visual Studio 2.0.5 Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error

Tags: visual-studio, mysql-connector

MysoL for Visual Studio 2.0.5 Setup Wizard ended prematurely
because of an error. Your system has not been modified. To
install this program at a later time, run Setup Wizard again.
Click the Finish button to exit the Setup Wizard.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtqRM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCOSO.png)
I installed it once at first, but I don't know if it was successful. This is because MysoL for Visual Studio is not displayed in the MySQL Installer. If it is because it has already been installed, it is caused by the problem when it is installed again. Then I wonder why it doesn't show up in MySQL Installer. Also, I don't know where MysoL for Visual Studio is installed, because I chose Typical to install it.

I want to know if I was successful in the installation or not.